# Sending a delete request to the url in an anchor tag

Tags: html, rest, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

How would I send a delete request to the specified URL (in the href attribute).

`<a href="/apartments/<%= @apartment.id %>">Delete</a>`

So far, I have tried `method = "delete"` as an attribute in the anchor tag.   I can get it to work by making a button like so,

```
  <form action = "/apartments/<%= @apartment.id %>" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

However, I'd prefer to keep it a link so that it is uniform with Edit, View Details, and other similar actions that appear with this particular item.

I'm using Sinatra.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an anchor tag (at least without JS). Links are meant to be idempotent.

Comment: Much appreciated! This answers my question.

Comment: DELETE requests actually [are idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent). they simply [aren't allowed in HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE)